# Dagger with androidx namespace not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger, androidx

I cannot get dagger to work with androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

```
// My dependencies
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
...
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.19'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.19'

// gradle.properties
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

// In my Fragment
...
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
...

public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this); // cannot resolve method here, AndroidInjection wants to use AndroidInjection.inject(android.app.Fragment);
        super.onAttach(context);        
    }
}
```

The same Fragment type error is present in my Activity class thus

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements HasFragmentInjector{

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment> fragmentInjector;

// incompatible  return type here, AndroidInjector wants to use AndroidInjector<android.app.Fragment>
    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector() { 
        return fragmentInjector;
    }

}
```

N/B
    1.Material Design Components says i should NOT touch any support libraries. `(AndroidInjection.inject<android.support.v4.app.Fragment>` gets dejetified,
    though my Dagger Component fails to generate).

```
2.Google says android.app.Fragment is depreciated.
```

How do i wire everything to have dagger work  with androidx namespace.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be resolved in next version (2.20) of Dagger. (See: https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.19)

For now, I think best way to solve your problem is using older version (2.16).